# Bookdown text runs into lower margin

Tags: r, pdf, margins, bookdown

Using up to date (from github)

bookdown::render_book("file.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_document2)

on R 3.4.1, on Windows, to generate a PDF document.

I get text running into the lower margin on the page...  See image. 
Note the page number"10" over-printed on the textual material. YAML unremarkable.

[image]

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: Oh, and this does not happen on all pages. The text has lots of tables and figures, all crossreferenced.

Answer (score 1):

It appears (rather strangely) that a blank line is required after a chunk.
Some combination of bookdown/pandoc/Latex  reacts rather poorly to this construct:

````
```{r chunkname}
 R code to make a table of figure
```
Table \@ref(fig:chunkname) blah blah
````

I'll build a reproducible example and send to bookdown as a bug.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue in 2023. In my case it does not seem to be linked to the lack of a line break (I don't have a code chunk anyway). 

Did you post the bug to Bookdown?